# Scan of data of a specific column in DynamoDB table - Reserved Keyword

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to scan all the items of a specific column from a dynamodb table:

[image: this is the table that i have in dynamodb AWS]

**I only want to get the data from the `data` column.** I am not interesting in the seqno and payload column. I am using this code right now

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('TablaLoraPF')
response  = table.scan(ProjectionExpression = 'data')
data = response['Items']


for x in range(80):
    print(data[x])
```

where with the ProjectionExpression I am choosing the data column and I am orinting 80 items of my table BUT what happened is when I run the code I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Moises Curvelo\Desktop\python dynamo\dynamo.py", line 15, in <module>
    response = table.get_item(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\factory.py", line 580, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\action.py", line 88, in _call_
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 495, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 914, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: **An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetItem operation: Invalid ProjectionExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: data
**
```

**But that only happens when I am choosing the `data` column**, because when I am choosing `seqno` column it print to me the correct items.

This is for my thesis.

This is what I get when I am using `seqno` **but that is not the item column that I need**.

[image: This is what I get when I am using seqno but that is not the item column that I need.]

This is what I am expecting but from the `data` column.

Comment: Why is half of this post in capslock? What is unclear about " Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: data"? `data` is a reserved keyword, not a good idea to use that as your column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes there is a need for everyone to use DynamoDB's reserved keyword names on their attribute names. In such cases, they can utilize the *expression attribute names* to map the reserved keyword name with another alternative name.

You can use the expression attribute names in your code as like below:

```
...
response  = table.scan(
        ExpressionAttributeNames = {'#data': 'data'},
        ProjectionExpression = '#data')
...
```